# php text + variable in function args

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $cellcount; $i++) { ?>
            <form method="post" action="options.php" class="home_page_settings_tile_<?php echo $cellcount ?>">
                <div class="home_page_settings_tile_cont">
                    <?php
                        settings_fields("home_tile_" . $cellcount );
                        do_settings_sections("options_cell_" . $cellcount);
                        submit_button();                        
                    ?>
            </div>
        </form>

        <?php } ?>
```

How can i insert text and count in function arguments?

Comment: I think you're going to need to explain your problem better. What function arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your arguments with a comma like so:

```
settings_field("home_title_", $cellcount);
```

`.` is the operator for [string concatenation in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Additionally, are you intending to render this element with a different number on each iteration of the loop? If so, I think what you want is this:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= $cellcount; $i++) { ?>
        <form method="post" action="options.php" class="home_page_settings_tile_<?php echo $i ?>">
            <div class="home_page_settings_tile_cont">
                <?php
                    settings_fields("home_tile_" . $i );
                    do_settings_sections("options_cell_" . $i);
                    submit_button();                        
                ?>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function myfunc("this is a string", $count);
?>
```

Use comma to separate the arguments.

```
<?php
    function myfunc(arg1, arg2);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use 
`settings_fields("home_tile_{$count}");` and it works fine.

Comment: You don't have a `$count` in your code. Did you mean `$i` perhaps?

Comment: yes, shure! `("options_cell_" . $i)` and ("options_cell_{$i}")` both works fine

Comment: Your answer appeared in the Low Quality Review queue (eg. someone flagged it because they think it should be deleted). You may want to [edit] the correct details into your answer.